# Is PJSIP OK to implement server side?

Tags: c++, sip, voip, pjsip

I want to develop a simple VoIP system. I want to implement both client and servers (proxy server, register server,...) with the same sip library. Is PJSIP OK to implement servers?

I use PJSIP on the client side and no problem.

is PJSIP suitable to implement servers?

 
Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using PjSIP to implement servers. In addition to the reason stated by MSalters, there are other issues you will notice when you start using PjSIP as a server. I have seen PjSIP going into a zombie state while having to maintain too many connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PJSIP implements the whole SIP protocol. So yes: it can also be used to implement a server.
The library comes with many samples, e.g. a proxy server. You can start from there.

Comment: PJSUA utility in pjproject (https://github.com/pjsip/pjproject/tree/master/pjsip-apps/src/pjsua) tree acts as SIP server, Zoiper Softphone (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zoiper.android.app&hl=en&gl=US) successfully connects and makes calls.

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation, not directly. Every connection is managed through one "object" called a conference bridge, which apparently is limited to 254 ports and a single thread. The documentation isn't very clear on this conference bridge (which is a shame, since it's the core object) so I'm not sure if each side of the call uses 1 full-duplex port or 2 half-duplex ports. Still, with just 128 connections in the best case, PJSIP isn't going to cut it for real servers. On a client, 128 connections obviously is sufficient.